# Angular - controlValueAccessor method writeValue() not being called

Tags: angular

Angular Version: 6.1

I'm trying to implement a custom  control using what Kara Erickson is calling a Composite ControlValueAccessor as shown in the presentation, [Angular Forms – Kara Erickson – AngularConnect 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8&t=2467s). The control's value should be set to one of the two child input values.

The issue is `writeValue()` seems to only be called initially and not on further value changes.

Here's a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-najdyu).

#### form.html

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && Submit(f)">
    <confirm-password name='password' ngModel #pwd='ngModel'></confirm-password>
    <div>{{pwd.status}}</div>
</form>
```

#### confirm-password.html

```html
<div [formGroup]='pass'>
  <label>Password:
    <input type="password" formControlName='pwd1' (blur)='onTouched()'>
  </label>
  <div *ngIf="controlDir.touched && controlDir.control.errors?.required" 
         class="error">Password is required.</div>

  <label>Please re-enter password:
    <input type="password" formControlName='pwd2' (blur)='onTouched()'>
  </label>
  <div class='error' *ngIf='controlDir.touched && controlDir.control.errors?.notEqual && 
                            !controlDir.errors?.required'>Passwords do not match.</div>
</div>
```

#### confirm-password.ts

```ts
import { Component, Self, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, AbstractControl, NgControl,
         ValidatorFn, Validators, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'confirm-password',
  templateUrl: './confirm-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm-password.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmPasswordComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, OnDestroy
{
  password: string; // the value of the control should be set to this value
  pass = new FormGroup({
    pwd1: new FormControl(),
    pwd2: new FormControl()
  });
  private onChange: (value: string) => void;
  private onTouched: (value: string) => void;
  private valueChanges: Subscription;

  constructor(@Self() public controlDir: NgControl)
  {
    controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    const control = this.controlDir.control;

    let myValidators = [
            Validators.required, 
            equalValidator(this.pass.controls.pwd1,
                           this.pass.controls.pwd2)
        ]
    // ovoid overwriting any existing validators
    let validators = control.validator
      ? [control.validator, ...myValidators]
      : [...myValidators];
    control.setValidators(validators);
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  writeValue(val: any)
  {
    /* whether everything inside of this method is commented out or not 
       doesn't seem to affect anything */
    console.log(val);
    //val && this.pass.setValue(val, {emitEvent: false});
    this.password = val;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (val: any) => void)
  {
    this.valueChanges = this.pass.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void)
  {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean)
  {
    disabled ? this.pass.disable() : this.pass.enable();
  }

  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    this.valueChanges.unsubscribe();
  }

}

export function equalValidator(el1, el2): ValidatorFn
{
  return (ctrl: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const notEqual = el1.value !== el2.value;

    return notEqual ?  {"notEqual": true} : null;
  };
}
```

Comment: Link to stackblitz editor plz

Comment: oops, didn't realize i linked to the wrong one. Should work now.

Comment: Works fine to me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukowfl?file=src/app/app.component.html - push the button

Comment: Did you change it? It no longer works at all for me with several errors in the console..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`writeValue` is called when you are changing control value (eg by setting backing ngModel property or controll value) not by user input.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hu2bfs?file=src/app/app.module.ts

I have removed errors caused by misused `ngModel`

As you can see, if you type into extra input new value and push the button, `writeValue` is called.

to wrap it up - `writeValue` is called when controller changes model value, and `writeValue` purpose is to do required stuff to reflect model changes by custom control.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Although you answered the question, I wish I would have reworded it and not assumed `writeValue` would solve my problem as it actually doesn't help me with the main goal of setting the `confirm-password` value to only one of the child control's value, as opposed to an object containing both. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: But how do I access `FormControl` if it's passed down from the parent? Surely it makes more sense to pass it down from a smart/dumb component point of view rather than creating it inside itself. You're also mixing reactive + template forms in the stackblitz. You shouldn't be using ngModel and FormControl.

Answer (score 20):

The purpose of `writeValue` is to **inform your component about changes on the parent component**. What you'll usually want to do with it is to bind the change from outside to a local variable.

In order to **inform the outside world about changes inside of your component**, you need to call the `onChange` method. You can call it, like you would usually call an event emitter.

I've put together a couple of examples here: https://www.tsmean.com/articles/angular/angular-control-value-accessor-example/

Comment: After reading about a dozen articles and tutorials, yours was the only one that finally made it make sense.  Thank you!  The key part was, "You don't provide implementations for the onTouch and onChange functions yourself. They will be provided by Angular. ... What you do get a say in is when you want to call those functions.".

Comment: I have read a lot of articles about that topic but you were the only one who can explain things Better. For me key part was understanding how we can change value of formcontrol  from parent (" eg reset, set value" you said) and understanding how angular interact by using writevalue and onchange. Thanks