# Formcontrol different value, stays unchanged after setting value via valueAccessor.writeValue()

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, directive

The problem is same as [Formcontrol invalid state unchanged after setting value via valueAccessor.writeValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065072/formcontrol-invalid-state-unchanged-after-setting-value-via-valueaccessor-writev) . But isn't solved. You can reply on his post.

In my case it's lik. I have directive for phone number:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[phonemask]'
})
export class PhoneDirective {

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event){
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event){
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }

  onInputChange(event, backspace){
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length === 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '$1');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '$1-$2');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 9) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '$1-$2-$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 9);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '$1-$2-$3');
    }
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
    console.log(newVal);
    console.log(this.ngControl.value)
  }
}
```

The problem is that in some cases console.log(newVal);
console.log(this.ngControl.value) has different values.

For example

```
111-1
1111

111-111-111
111-111-1111
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formcontrol invalid state unchanged after setting value via valueAccessor.writeValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065072/formcontrol-invalid-state-unchanged-after-setting-value-via-valueaccessor-writev)

Comment: @TimLepage like its said. I can set maxlength on input and its works fine. But i want to know in the future why does this happens.

Comment: Did you try `this.ngControl.control.setValue(newVal)` ?

Comment: @Gilsdav im getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667435/angular-ngmodelchange-is-late-when-updating-ngmodel/63670081#63670081 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from [this answer](http://%5Bthis%20answer%5D(https://stackoverflow.com/a/63670811/9632621)):

Angular has *default value accessors* for certain elements, such as for `input type='text'`, `input type='checkbox'` etc...

A `ControlValueAccessor` is the *middleman* between the VIEW layer and the MODEL layer. When a user types into an input, the VIEW notifies the `ControlValueAccessor`, which has the job to inform the MODEL.

For instance, when the `input` event occurs, the `onChange` method of the `ControlValueAccessor` will be called. [Here's how](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L93-L101) `onChange` looks like **for every** `ControlValueAccessor`:

```js
function setUpViewChangePipeline(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {
  dir.valueAccessor!.registerOnChange((newValue: any) => {
    control._pendingValue = newValue;
    control._pendingChange = true;
    control._pendingDirty = true;

    if (control.updateOn === 'change') updateControl(control, dir);
  });
}
```

The magic happens in [`updateControl`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L112-L117):

```js
function updateControl(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {
  if (control._pendingDirty) control.markAsDirty();
  control.setValue(control._pendingValue, {emitModelToViewChange: false});
 
  // !
  dir.viewToModelUpdate(control._pendingValue);
  control._pendingChange = false;
}
```

`dir.viewToModelUpdate(control._pendingValue);` is what invokes the `ngModelChange` event in the custom directive. What this means is that the **model value** is the value from the input(in lowercase). And because `ControlValueAccessor.writeValue` **only** writes the value to the VIEW, there will be a *delay* between the VIEW's value and the MODEL's value.

It's worth mentioning that `FormControl.setValue(val)` will write `val` to **both** layers, VIEW and MODEL, but if we were to used this, there would be an **infinite loop**, since `setValue()` internally calls `viewToModelUpdate`(because the MODEL has to be updated), and `viewToModelUpdate` calls `setValue()`.

---

So, a possible solution would be to add this snippet to your directive:

```js
ngOnInit () {
  const initialOnChange = (this.ngControl.valueAccessor as any).onChange;

  (this.ngControl.valueAccessor as any).onChange = (value) => initialOnChange(this.makeChangesToInput(value));
}

@HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
onModelChange(event){
  this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.makeChangesToInput(event, false));
}

@HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
keydownBackspace(event){
  this.ngControl.control.setValue(this.makeChangesToInput(event, true));

  // if you want the `ngModelChange` handler from above to be called
  // this.ngControl.control.setValue(this.makeChangesToInput(event, true), { emitViewToModelChange: true }); 
}

makeChangesToInput(value, backspace){
  let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
  if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
    newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
  }
  if (newVal.length === 0) {
    newVal = '';
  } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
    newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '$1');
  } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
    newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '$1-$2');
  } else if (newVal.length <= 9) {
    newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '$1-$2-$3');
  } else {
    newVal = newVal.substring(0, 9);
    newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '$1-$2-$3');
  }

  return newVal;
}
```

The gist is that you should perform any changes on the input value at the VIEW layer, before sending the altered value to the `ControlValueAccessor`.

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for. I get this.