# How to create a custom radio button angular component that works with ReactiveForms

Tags: angular

I created a custom radio button that basically just stores the current value in the model attribute and in the styling checks to see if the model and value equal each other. This code works perfectly fine when using template forms and the `[(ngModel)]` attribute on the tag. However, when I try this with reactive forms and the `formControlName` attribute it doesn't seem to get the values from the other components. It seems that the model is not getting updated. Am I doing something wrong?
Here is my basic code (I've removed some things that aren't too important)

Here is a stackblitz of the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rl3sez

It seems that the defaulting works correctly, when building the component using `FormBuilder` I default it to true and the first item is selected; however, when I click on the second item the first is not deselected.

Any ideas what I am missing?

### UPDATE

I managed to find an ugly solution which seems to highlight the issue I am having. If I patch the value to the control on every change it works correctly. I think that for some reason the write value isn't getting called correctly.
Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgu2fj

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. Radio inputs work natively in HTML, but here, you're not creating radio buttons, but rather custom components. Could you please share your template code ? I might think where it comes from, but I'm going to need the template to confirm it.

Comment: @Maryannah I added the parts of the template, which I think are relevant.

Comment: Well it's way too little but it indeed confirms what I was thinking : if you do not use inputs of type radio, then they won't manage themselves ! You can't expect buttons to be coupled without code ...

Comment: Well using template forms works because the write value gets called. Why wouldn't the write value get called in a reactive form? Also I don't want to use a radio button. I guess I can if I need to, but I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation. Just because it works for 1 use-case, doesn't mean it's working correctly ! It's just a coincidence. But then again, if you provided a [mcve], I could tell you what's wrong with it ...

Comment: @Maryannah I added a stackblitz to the original post for you to see the problem I am having

Comment: @Maryannah I have added a hack that seems to solve my issue (as an update to the original question). Any chance you would know of a better way to fix it based on the hack provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out that the main issue I was having is that writeValue is not called on reactive forms. It's what I was noticing and then I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565659/angular-controlvalueaccessor-method-writevalue-not-being-called) which explains that my issue makes sense since writeValue is only called when using ngModel.

In order to fix this I manually call the writeValue function on each change here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmkedk?file=src/app/radio-button.component.ts